# How to know if you're running out of space with Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento-cloud

Sometimes I got many issues related to space in my Magento Cloud, then I clean up logs and database reports and it starts to work again.

How could I measure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run these two commands below to measure the allocated disk and the percentage of usage.

#### Check database

```
$ magento-cloud db:size -e production 

+----------------+-----------------+--------+
| Allocated disk | Estimated usage | % used |
+----------------+-----------------+--------+
| 8.0 GiB        | 6.1 GiB         | ~ 76%  |
+----------------+-----------------+--------+
```

#### Check files

```
$ magento-cloud mount:size -e production

+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| Mount(s)   | Size(s)   | Disk    | Used    | Available | % Used |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| app/etc    | 196 KiB   | 7.8 GiB | 3.8 GiB | 4.0 GiB   | 48.8%  |
| pub/media  | 3.4 GiB   |         |         |           |        |
| pub/static | 4 KiB     |         |         |           |        |
| var        | 355.1 MiB |         |         |           |        |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

If you want to improve it, check it at [DevDocs - Manage disk space](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/manage-disk-space.html#application-disk-space).

Answer (score 0):

I use following:
ssh your_cloud_environment and perfrom
`df -h`.
It shows used and available disk space on each of the Filesystems (some of them are shared between the nodes and some are not).